# react native: what is way to make animation arrow to accordion list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

i try find away or example to animation of rotate arrow of accordion list.

[image]

i want to rotate it with animation when i open my list , how to do it ?

```
<Accordion
            renderHeader={_renderHeader}
            animation={true}
            expanded={true}
            dataArray={dataArray}
            headerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: '#b5e5ff',
              borderColor: 'black',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              // height: 80,
            }}
            contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ddecf8', height: 80 }}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform: rotate(180deg);` this and a transition let's say `transition: transform 0.6s ease;` put the transform in a different class and bind it to a click event.

Comment: Your code already wrapped on Accordion component. to implement the rotation, we need to wrap the icon on Animated.View.

If you want, you can see my code on my project:
https://github.com/PrayaAmadigaPitasa/react-native-design-kit/blob/master/src/components/expansion-panel/ExpansionPanel.tsx